# Optimization on a grid

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I worked a lot on defining the problem so I will be grateful to get input if i'm not clear enouth and I will fix the question.
We have a grid made out of uniform points on $[x,y],$  $x,y\in[0,1],$ every 0.1 we have a point.
At each point we have a function of variables $k_1$ and $k_2$ and the point $f(x,y,k_1,k_2)$ which give us the cost at the point and the value of the point.
We run an optimization at each point of the grid and get a pareto front of cost and value.
we are looking for the variables $k_1$ and $k_2$ at each point, we need that the cost will be monotnic, I mean if at $[0,0]$ the cost is $2$ and at $[1, 0]$ the cost is $3$ at $[2 ,0]$ the cost should be around $4$ and not around $2.$ we also need that $k_1$ and $k_2$ will be monotonic so if for $[0,0]$ $k_1=k_2=1$ and for[1,0] $k_1=k_2=2$ for $[2,0]$ we shouldn't get $k_1 = k_2 = 1.2.$
Is there a way to find these points on each pareto?

Thanks

Comment: There are many things not clear to me. What do you mean by the word point, and is your use of that word coherent with your own definition?

Comment: let say the problem is a square 1 meter sheet of metal on which we want to attach a different material every 10 cm. $k_1$ and $k_2$ will be temperature and heat capacity. we want that  cost and temperature and heat capacity to be monotonic

Comment: Thanks for this example. What is a point? And what is the role of the function $f$ in your metal sheet example?

Comment: a point is the physical place to attach the different piece of material, $f$ is the function that gives us the cost and value. It isn't needed here I have a pareto for each point which I got by evaluating $f$

Comment: Could it be that the phrase "$k_1$ and $k_2$ will be monotonic" should read "$f$ is monotonic in $k_1$ and $k_2$ separately"?

Comment: No, $f$ is the way to evaluate cost and value, that was already done we don't have $f$ anymore. we want to find $k_1$ and $k_2$ that are monotonic and give us monotonic cost that will belong to the pareto. Is this clearer now? Thanks